# Find which makefile sets a variable in included make

Tags: makefile

I am working on a large project with many Makefile dependencies included at some point or another. In many of these make files, the compiler `CC` is conditionally set depending on the target architecture.

In several files the `CC` variable is set to `gcc`. I am currently facing an issue that the variable has been set to `gcc` instead of the platform I expect.

I am wondering if there is a way to trace *where* a variable has been set in an included Make structure, save from changing each instance of the variable to `gcc1` or something.

Comment: I am aware of the [origin](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Origin-Function.html) function, which can tell me that it came from a file, but not which file.

Comment: *Recursive* Make, in which one Make process *invokes* another (`$(MAKE) -f otherMakefile ...`), or *inclusion* (`include otherMakefile`)? I suspect it's the latter, in which case a crude-but-effective approach is to insert e.g. `$(info checkpoint 5: CC is $(CC))` here and there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `-p` option to your invocation of `make` and it will print make's entire internal database.  Included before every variable generated will be the makefile name and line number where it was set.